# Selenium IDE 2.9.1 is not showing the selenium script after recording

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I just installed selenium IDE 2.9.1 and recorded a testcase. But when inspect the source, It is showing only the HTML, not selenium script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.google.co.in/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/?gws_rd=ssl</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=Passwd</td>
    <td>arunkojndfjn</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=signIn</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

What to do to get the selenium script ? Thanks.

Comment: This is the expected display if you view a test case recorded in Selenium IDE in a text editor. When you say 'get the selenium script' what exactly do you mean? Are you trying to get the script in a format to run in selenium webdriver? e.g. Java/Python etc.

Comment: Yes..Smith...@Jsmith2800,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert a selenium IDE script into one that can be run in Webdriver isn't done by viewing the file, as the file itself is written in a selenium specific format of HTML. You need to use the options within selenium IDE itself. If you go to "File > Export Test Case as" you will get a list of various languages you can export the test as.